# MySQL concurrent INSERTs

Tags: mysql, locking, concurrency

I have a MySQL database with InnoDB tables.
There are different client processes making `SELECT` (to check the existence of a value) and `INSERT` or `UPDATE` (depending on the result of the select) statements.
What I fear is a possible concurrent access to data causing only `INSERT`s and no `UPDATE`s.
Is **LOCK Table WRITE** the only solution?

Comment: If i understand correctly you want to avoid race conditions on InnoDB?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

Pseudo code:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT some_column INTO @value FROM table_name WHERE ... FOR UPDATE;
IF @value = 'some value' THEN
  INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(...);
END IF;
INSERT INTO referenced_table VALUES(...);
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

If this table has no other foreign keys attached to it you can try INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE or REPLACE INTO (this one deletes an existing row and inserts a new one)

This would save you having to select first then insert or update, however it requires that you have a unique key to base the checks on

Comment: Thanks ssmusoke! The solution you adviced is perfect for what I described, but I just noticed that my situation is a bit more complicated.
I have a table that has a PK and the field checked by the SELECT.
Based on the result of the select i have to 
- create a new row on this table and on the referenced tables 

OR

- create only rows in the referenced tables.

Sorry for giving a misleading description

Comment: If you are using an ORM (object relational mapper) in your application this will be done automatically.

If you read here http://thomashunter.name/blog/mysql-replace-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update/ you will find that ON DUPLICATE KEY update does not delete the existing row like replace into (needs to be confirmed though)